# Chrome indicator icon multiplies randomly

Tags: google-chrome, system-tray

Everyone is complaining how icons are missing and here I am with 10 of them.

It's happening over a span of few hours, so I can't catch the exact moment over what's triggering it. But this is my tray after a few days.

[image]

I don't particularly mind it, but it's pushing other icons to the other screen, so buttons start overlapping.

[image: Ubuntu 18.04.2]

[image]